# Change the dimensions of an externally loaded page

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I change the dimensions of a page that I am loading into a div?

Here is the script that I am using to load the page into the div:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" onclick="load_wp_1()">xxx</a></li>
      <script type="text/javascript">   
         function load_wp_1(){
            var wp = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="wp_1.html" ></object>';
            wp.style.width = "500px";
}
     </script>
```

That does not seem to work as the page that loads is much smaller (there are scroll bars inside it). The CSS associated with "content" div is the following:

```
#content {
float: left;
width: 590px;
padding: 40px 30px 0px 30px;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your code doesn't show the `div` - I'm guessing it's loaded inside an iframe? If so, you can't touch it.

Comment: Why are you using an object instead of an iframe? You get pretty much the same effect but without as many features or as much browser support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set the width of a **string** of HTML.

You need to get the DOM element that you are generating and set the width of that.

The easiest way to do that is to create the element using standard DOM in the first place instead of mashing HTML strings about the place.

```
var container = document.getElementById("content");
// Erase existing content
container.innerHTML = "";
var frame = document.createElement('iframe'); // Better supported than object elements for this
frame.src = "wp_1.html";
frame.style.width = "500px"; // Set on the frame, not on the frames container
container.appendChild(frame);
```

Comment: Using that just erases everything in the content div. What I am working with is a page that already has certain text/images in the content div that I need replaced by the external page onclick.